# Should I use "might" or "might have" in a past context?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Here is the sentence from C. S. Lewis' The Magician's Nephew:

> Down and down they rushed, first through darkness and then through a mass of vague and whirling shapes which **might have** been almost anything.

As far as I know, *might* refers to the present and future, and *might have* refers to the past. This sentence is in the past, so I think that *might* would automatically refer to the same past moment, and *might have* would refer to the moment that was earlier.

Still, I can't understand the reason of using *might have* here because it's apparent that the characters' journey and the whirling shapes were at the same time.

Why is *might have* used here, and what would the meaning be if we used *might*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*MODAL<sup>Past</sup> have VERB<sup>PastPpl</sup>* is the construction English uses to express a past-tense 'irrealis' (non-factual, hypothetical, unreal) situation corresponding to the present-tense irrealis construction *MODAL<sup>Past</sup> VERB<sup>Infinitive</sup>*.

If this sentence were in the present tense, *might* would be used to express non-factuality:

> They are rushing down and down ... through vague and whirling shapes which ***might be*** almost anything.

That in effect "uses up" the 'past' form of *may*, so if you want to move this into the past tense, you have to use what I call a 'sham perfect' of *be* as a tense marker:

> They rushed down and down ... through vague and whirling shapes which ***might have been*** almost anything.

Comment: Several paragraphs below, there is this sentence: "The stone of which everything was built seemed to be red, but that might only be because of the curious light."
Is this a real situation in the past, so we use the past form of _may_ which is _might_? On the contrary, in my post, we have an unreal situation, so we should use _might have_. Am I right?

Comment: @athlonusm That's pretty much right -- it represents a backshifted "That *may* only be because &c". Note, however, that in PDE "That *may* be because ... " can also be expressed as "That *might* be because ...". *Might* is gradually taking over much of the function of *may*, and there it would not express non-factuality, merely the same possibility that *may* expresses. That *might* does **not** have to be backshifted in a past-tense context; it  can express exactly the same thing in both present and past contexts.

Answer (score 0):

"Might" suggests possibility without any prohibitive conditions. There was no telling what those shapes were. They could have been almost anything. The possibilities were almost boundless.